# Need to Remove Horizontal Scrollbar

Tags: horizontal-scrolling

For some reason I randomly have a horizontal scroll on a website I'm working on. It appears to only be on the home page. I have tried playing with padding and margins on this page and can't seem to fix it. I know I can just use the overflow:hidden css, but I really don't want to have to do this. The site I'm working on is located here:
http://www.wattins.abncomputers.com/.
I would really appreciate any help anyone can give me cuz I think I've just been messing with it for too long and need another set of eyes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: CSS]

You have a div with `.so-image-grid-wrapper` with margin, you need to remove that

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much! I knew I just needed another set of eyes